# Dynamically change select input in Bootstrap Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to set some objects in a Bootstrap-Vue form select which I get via JSON.
The JSON is made up of teacher objects from the following fields:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is put the name and surname in the select list, that is the full name.

I have already managed to do this via a computed property by processing the list.
But now I want that when I select a teacher, the list of courses is filtered according to the chosen teacher.

To do this I need the teacher's email, which I can't recover, having processed the teachers to get the full name.
Consequently, I can't even update the list of courses based on the teacher chosen.

This is the code for the template:

```html
<b-form-group
  id="input-group-3"
  label="Docente:"
  label-for="input-3"
>
  <b-form-select
    v-model="teacher"
    :options="teachers"
    value-field="item"
    text-field="fullName"
    required
    @change="filterCourse"
  ></b-form-select>
  <div class="mt-3">
    Selected: <strong>{{ teacher }}</strong>
  </div>
</b-form-group>
```

This is the script code:

```js
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      teacher: "",
      course: "",
    };
  },

  created: function() {
    this.GetActiveTeachers();
    this.GetActiveCourses();
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      ActiveTeacherList: "StateActiveTeachers",
      ActiveCourseList: "StateActiveCourses",
      FilteredTeacherList: "StateTeacherByCourse",
      FilteredCourseList: "StateCourseByTeacher",
    }),

    teachers: function() {
      let list = [];
      this.ActiveTeacherList.forEach((element) => {
        let teacher = element.name + " " + element.surname;
        list.push(teacher);
      });
      return list;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      "GetActiveTeachers",
      "GetActiveCourses",
      "GetCourseByTeacher",
      "GetTeacherByCourse",
      "AssignTeaching",
    ]),

    async filterCourse() {
      const Teacher = {
        teacherEmail: "john.doe@gmail.com", // For testing purpose
      };
      try {
        await this.GetCourseByTeacher(Teacher);
      } catch {
        console.log("ERROR");
      }
    },

    async filterTeacher() {
      const Course = {
        title: "Programming", // For testing purpose
      };
      try {
        await this.GetTeacherByCourse(Course);
      } catch {
        console.log("ERROR");
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using the simplest notation that Bootstrap Vue offers for form selects, an array of strings.

I suggest you switch to use their [object notation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#options-property), which will allow you to specify the `text` (what you show in the list) separately from the `value` (what's sent to the select's `v-model`).

This way, you'll be able to access all the data of the teacher object that you need, while still being able to display only the data you'd like.

We can do this by swapping the `forEach()` in your `teachers` computed property for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
teachers() {
  return this.ActiveTeacherList.map((teacher) => ({
    text: teacher.name + " " + teacher.surname,
    value: teacher
  }));
},
```

Then, all you need to do is update your `filterCourse()` handler to use the new syntax, eg.:

```js
async filterCourse() {
  const Teacher = {
    teacherEmail: this.teacher.email,
  };
  try {
    await this.GetCourseByTeacher(Teacher);
  } catch {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
},
```

As a final note, if you don't want or need the full object as the value, then you can mold it to be whatever you need, that's the beauty of this syntax.
For example, you want the full name and email, instead of the parts:

```js
value: { 
  fullName: teacher.name + " " + teacher.surname,
  email: teacher.email
}
```

Comment: Why I'm getting this error: `Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null"` ?

Comment: My bad, the parameters in the select form were wrong

Comment: I'm still having a problem, during the first load of the application `courses` computed property is null and it gives me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`. To avoid the error I have to use for the first time the array in the select form without computing it, after that I can switch to the computed array

Comment: @Raul Another possible solution would be to make the default value of `courses` an empty array `[]` rather than `null`. This would prevent that error, since `map()` is valid to call on an empty array; it will simply return a new empty array.

Comment: to solve this error before the computing I check if the array is null, if it is null return `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's two different options you can do.

One would be to generate the `<option>`'s inside the select yourself, using a `v-for` looping over your teachers, and binding the `email` property to the `value`, and displaying the `name` and `surname` inside the option.

This will make your `<b-select>`'s v-model return the chosen teachers e-mail, which you can then use in your filter.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedTeacher: null,
      activeTeachers: [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Dickerson",
          "surname": "Macdonald",
          "email": "dickerson.macdonald@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Larsen",
          "surname": "Shaw",
          "email": "larsen.shaw@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Geneva",
          "surname": "Wilson",
          "email": "geneva.wilson@example.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-select v-model="selectedTeacher">
    <option v-for="teacher in activeTeachers" :value="teacher.email">
      {{ teacher.name }} {{ teacher.surname }}
    </option>
  </b-select>

  {{ selectedTeacher }}
</div>
```

---

The other option would be to change your computed to return an array of *objects* instead of simple strings as you're currently doing.

By default `<b-select>` expects the properties `value` and `text` if you use an array of objects in the `options` prop.

Here you would bind the `email` for each teacher to the `value`, and the `name` and `surname` to the `text` prop.

This will make your `<b-select>`'s v-model return the chosen teachers e-mail, which you can then use in your filter.

Reference: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#options-property

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedTeacher: null,
      activeTeachers: [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Dickerson",
          "surname": "Macdonald",
          "email": "dickerson.macdonald@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Larsen",
          "surname": "Shaw",
          "email": "larsen.shaw@example.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Geneva",
          "surname": "Wilson",
          "email": "geneva.wilson@example.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    teacherOptions() {
      return this.activeTeachers.map(teacher => ({
        value: teacher.email,
        text: `${teacher.name} ${teacher.surname}`
      }));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-select v-model="selectedTeacher" :options="teacherOptions"></b-select>

  {{ selectedTeacher }}
</div>
```